# Best way to exchange information between 2 different servers in java

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I have my server side plugin, i have to send some value from my server to another server hosted on 2 different locations.
1. Server Side plugin - Hosted on some server i dont know where it is.
2. Web Application - is my application and hosted location i know.

How to exchange data from that server to my application.
We have the privilege to deploy the plugins in some folder but i dont know where it is hosted. But i can use approach to send data.

Please let me know!!!

Regards,
Chandan

Comment: Before you can do anything, you must find out where the other server is located. Otherwise, your question is a bit too broad and I doubt you will get any answers if you don't give us a more detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to exchange data between different servers:

- Shared database
- Shared filesystem
- exposure of restful web services
- exposure of soap web services
- rmi
- socket connection
- shared application that operates as a bridge between the two servers

Each solution has pro and cons. Some needs polling (shared database and filesystem for example), some others not. Some needs just an exposure of a port (web services, socket, web services) other needs additional requirements (for example a shared database needs a database and that database must be visible to both applications).

Generally if you need very fast communication with high traffic load the best solution is a socket (as for client server in databases for example).
Otherwyse choose a solution more human readable and simpler to code.